# Build CI Trigger Not Working - Private Repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We are using BitBucket repos hosted on-premises behind a firewall restricting access outside our network. I configured a self-hosted build agent that is also internal so it can access our repos.

Everything is working fairly smoothly with our build pipelines except for one issue, continuous integration. The builds have to be triggered manually or run on a schedule.

Is there a way to enable CI in Azure DevOps using a private repo? We are using the 'Other Git' source type. I'm not exactly sure how polling works in Azure DevOps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you have enabled CI for your build.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed. 'Enable continous integration' is checked with a polling interval of 180 seconds and branch filter set to include 'master'. My settings are slightly different since I am using an 'Other Git' source type.

Comment: It should be working, a CI build should trigger after 3mins of your check-in as per polling interval setup. Can you please share the screenshots from "Get Source step" and the Trigger tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the polling interval as 180 seconds, it means,the new build pipeline will have a 3 minutes delay to run. I set the polling interval as below.
[image]
In the build pipeline history, you can see the effect.
[image]

For this newest commit, I record the commit time as 10:43. And in build pipeline, the CI build will queue in 10:46.
[image]
[image]

In the pipeline log -> Check out, you can see the commit id. And this commit points to the newest commit.

[image]

So I think this feature worked as expected, you can check your build pipeline history to confirm it.